# Monitor power brick

Tags: power-supply, power

I was just given a 27" monitor that needs a 19v 3.34A power brick. However, the brick is missing. I have a 20v 7a brick from an old laptop. Can I use that, or does the power need to be exact?

In other research I came across this comment.
"Voltage means less than the current rating of the power supply. Your power supply should always be able to safely supply more current than the device will draw."

Comment: I often find that the connectors may not be standard in some monitors. If its a barrel plug, also take note of the internal and external diameter and the polarity...

Answer (score 2):

If it were me, I would give it a try. You will want to make sure that the connector is the same and that the polarity is the same as the old adapter. Generally with electronics nowadays there are built-in voltage regulators that will accept power even if the voltage is a bit off. If the monitor usually takes 19 volts, then you would probably be able to get away with any voltages in the range of 17 - 21, although I cannot guarantee that.

The current rating of 7 amps is greater than the old 3.34 amp adapter but this isn't a problem as that is just an upper limit to the current the adapter can supply.

Good luck!